# Why in Rails 3.2 is an explicit link directive required for "cupertino" theme, even though we precompile that asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline

I am running Rails 3.2.  I have integrated the "cupertino" theme from the ThemeRoller Gallery (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).  As variable themes are not yet supported in Rails 3.2, I simply copied cupertino images to `./app/assets/images/images`, and placed cupertino CSS styles sheet into `./app/assets/stylesheets/cupertino.css.scss`.

I did not add anything to application.css.  My understanding is that the asset-pipeline will simply precompile any SCSS files that are located under `./app/assets/stylesheets`.  So far so good.  In `application.rb`, I have the right property set to true:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Here is where things get interesting.  If I pop up the jQuery datepicker, for example, I DO NOT get cupertino themes!  Ok.  This is easy to deal with.  I just explicitly declare a link to cupertino styles:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "cupertino" %>
```

For my development environment, this works!  I raise the jQuery datepicker again, and cupertino themes appear!  If I open the HTML view, you can see the corresponding link-directive that picks up cupertino styles:

```
<link href="/assets/cupertino.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In my production environment, the `stylesheet_link_tag` does not work!  I believe this is because assets are precompiled in production, and Rails is not able to find the "keyed" version of cupertino.css.  That is, I would expect something like this if `stylesheet_link_tag` worked properly:

```
<link href="/assets/cupertino-40e24d89d5768c02a1373032957ebd02.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So, I then look at my production logs where I precompile assets.  Guess what?  cupertino is precompiled!

```
$ tail -100 log/production.log
...
Compiled cupertino.css  (729ms)  (pid 5325)
...
```

I replace the `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "cupertino" %>` directive with an explicit link-directive that loads the unkeyed version of the cupertino styles sheet:

```
<link href="/assets/cupertino.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

That works!  On both development and production.  But the mystery intensifies.  On production, I open the keyed version of `applications.css`, i.e., all of the precompiled styles.  I search for `cupertino`.  Guess what?  cupertino styles were precompiled; here is one such style that I unwound from the compacted, precompiled resource:

```
.ui-icon {
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-image:url("/assets/jquery-ui/cupertino/ui-icons_72a7cf_256x240-cd87f27304052bb2d63abd3680bb2bbd.png")
}
```

We immediately see a path-related issue.  Not surprising based on other comments I have seen.
I move images from `./app/assets/images/images` to `./app/assets/images/jquery-ui/cupertino`.  Same problem recurs.  Same resolution resolves problem.

**QUESTION**:  why isn't a fingerprinted version of `cupertino.css` found in production, even when all evidence suggests that resource was precompiled?

Comment: What happens if you do RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the missing magic.  Along with Richard Hulse's suggestion, I go to the manifest file `application.css`, and add the line:

```
 *= require cupertino
```

and wola!, cupertino is precompiled:

```
$ ls -c1 ./public/assets/cupertino*
./public/assets/cupertino-3235459a735b4f142b96270d04b2626e.css
./public/assets/cupertino-3235459a735b4f142b96270d04b2626e.css.gz
./public/assets/cupertino.css
./public/assets/cupertino.css.gz
```

After deploying my webapp, this directive works correctly on both production
and development environments:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "cupertino" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the file name to the precompile array to tell Rails that you want to use it in production. This is in production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(cupertino.css)
```

Comment: Does not work.  However, I concur with Richard Hulse's assertion that the `config.assets.precompile` should be there in order to use `stylesheet_link_tag`.  Something else is going on in the asset-pipeline / precompilation.

`thisfeller`:  I always precompile with `RAILS_ENV=production`; I do this on my development environment before posting the webapp to heroku.  The production/precompilation logs I sited earlier were extracted from my development environment.